# Obtaining RAM usage per logon session in PowerShell

Tags: windows-10, memory, powershell

I want to get the memory used per session through a PowerShell function. I am only interested in disconnected sessions. In the task manager, I can see the memory used per sessionID:

[image]

I tried to obtain the mem used in MB in PowerShell through the following script:

```
# Get all user sessions
$sessions = qwinsta | Where-Object { $_ -match 'Disc' }
$procs = get-process # | where-object {$_.ProcessName -ne "Idle"}

foreach ($session in $sessions)
{
    $sessionId = ($session -split '\s+')[2]
    $usrprocs = $procs | where-object {$_.SessionId -eq $sessionId}
    $usrMem=0
    foreach($proc in $usrprocs)
    {
         $usrMem = $usrMem + [int64]($proc.WorkingSet64/(1024*1024))         
    }
    echo "$sessionId, $usrMem"
}
```

But this gives me the following result:

```
20, 481
21, 451
22, 670
23, 763
24, 949
```

Which is nowhere near the mem used listed in the task manager. How can I obtain the RAM per session?

**Update**
Based on Vomit IT's suggestion, I did this, but its still giving me the wrong values:

```
# Get all user sessions
$sessions = qwinsta | Where-Object { ($_ -match 'Disc') }

foreach ($session in $sessions)
{
    $sessionId = ($session -split '\s+')[2]
    $usrprocs = Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.SessionId -eq $sessionId }
    $usrMem=0
    foreach($proc in $usrprocs)
    {
         $usrMem = $usrMem + [int](Get-Counter -Counter "\Process($($proc.Name))\Working Set - Private").CounterSamples.CookedValue / 1KB      
    }
    echo "$sessionId, $usrMem"
}
```

result

```
20, 808288
22, 830872
23, 806404
24, 806312
25, 802892
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## PowerShell (most optimal)

> Thanks Vomit ;) that works as I wanted, and allowed me to see the RAM
> usage per disconnected session. I did experience that `Get-Counter` is
> very slow, each call in a loop takes ~1 sec. So I opted to go with
> `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process` and then
> get the working set private. –
> [rinkert](https://superuser.com/users/823234/rinkert)

As highlighted by the OP, the performance of `Get-Counter` is not as optimal as `Get-CimInstance` when retrieving property values from the corresponding class. This variation of PowerShell incorporates this consideration, offering improved performance if it is of importance to you.

```
$session = quser | Where-Object { ($_ -match 'Disc') } 2>&1;
$sId = $session | ForEach-Object  { ($_ -split '\s+')[2]};
$processes = Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.SessionId -in $sId };

foreach ($process in $processes) {
    $workingSet = [int](Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process -Filter "Name='$($process.Name)'").WorkingSetPrivate / 1KB;
    "$($process.Id), $($workingSet)";
};
```

**A Gotcha**

Please note that the above solution may have issues accessing certain `WorkingSetPrivate` property values in the class. Consider adding conditional logic to ignore null and zero values for a more desirable output, if necessary.

```
foreach ($process in $processes) {
    $instance = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process -Filter "Name='$($process.Name)'"
    if ($instance.WorkingSetPrivate -ne $null -and $instance.WorkingSetPrivate -gt 0) {
        $workingSet = [int]($instance.WorkingSetPrivate / 1KB)
        "$($process.Id), $($workingSet)"
    }
}
```

---

## Other Solutions

**Incorporating this solution into your task accordingly** will resolve this problem. This example is a simple version and accurate to match the values shown in the **Task Manager** as you prefer for active private RAM.

**Essentially this...**

- Puts the `Get-Process` command into a `ForEach-Object` loop to iterate each returned process and property values.
- Uses a `PSCustomObject`, within storing the `PID` in one field.
- Uses `Get-Counter`, specifying the `Working Set - Private` to return, casting it to an `[int]` and then dividing that by `1 KB` in another field.

The results will return a column with the `PID` and another column with the `Memory (active private)` matching what you see from Task Manager and the `Details` tab view there for those properties.

### PowerShell

```
$session = quser | Where-Object { ($_ -match 'Disc') } 2>&1;
$sId = $session | ForEach-Object  { ($_ -split '\s+')[2]};

Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.SessionId -in $sId } | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "PID" = $_.Id
        "Memory (active private)" = [int](Get-Counter -Counter "\Process($($_.Name))\Working Set - Private").CounterSamples.CookedValue / 1KB
    };
};
```

#### Output

```
  PID Memory (active private)
  --- -----------------------
16464                     164
25920                     164
11412                     264
12284                     712
18488                     712
20084                     712
 3660                   96952
10416                   96952
18424                   96952
 1408                   59000
```

#### PowerShell (another variation)

Here's another variation in PowerShell using a [`ForEach`](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach.html) *loop statement* which outputs just the values as desired comma separated more similar to your existing logic in case this matters.

```
$session = quser | Where-Object { ($_ -match 'Disc') } 2>&1;
$sId = $session | ForEach-Object  { ($_ -split '\s+')[2]};

$processes = Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.SessionId -in $sId };

foreach ($process in $processes) {
    $workingSet = (Get-Counter -Counter "\Process($($process.Name))\Working Set - Private").CounterSamples.CookedValue / 1KB;
    "$($process.Id), $([int]$workingSet)";
};
```

#### Output

```
16464, 164
25920, 164
11412, 264
12284, 728
18488, 728
20084, 728
3660, 97732
10416, 97732
18424, 97732
1408, 57576
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Everything you wanted to know about PSCustomObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.3)
- [Get-CimInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/get-ciminstance?view=powershell-7.3)
- [Get-Counter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-counter?view=powershell-7.3)
- [Powershell Get a specific process counter with id process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067565/powershell-get-a-specific-process-counter-with-id-process)

Comment: Thanks! I tried to incorporate this into the rest of the script, but couldnt manage to get the right numbers out. See the update in my post. could you demonstrate how to get the sum of the processes memory per sessionId?

Comment: @rinkert I just made an edit and updated both output samples I tested this one. This new section named **PowerShell (another variation)** matches the output format as in your question example, and it also uses a `foreach` statement block rather than `ForEach-Object` as your question example uses. Let me know how it goes when you get to it. I also cleaned up some of my older comments here, but I got your back still regardless, just hit me back!!

Comment: Thanks Vomit ;) that works as I wanted, and allowed me to see the RAM usage per disconnected session. I did experience that `Get-Counter` is very slow, each call in a loop takes ~1 sec. So I opted to go with `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PerfRawData_PerfProc_Process` and then get the working set private.